# Displaying small window that look like an options screen

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo

How can i achive this using expo react native. When you press three dots it should show up and when you press somewhere else on the screen it should disapear.

[desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOaXz.png)

I was looking for a solution but I didn't find anything that will look like that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the package react-native-walkthrough-tooltip. You will simply have to trigger the tooltip on press of button and add style to it as per your design.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip

```
import Tooltip from 'react-native-walkthrough-tooltip';

<Tooltip
  isVisible={this.state.toolTipVisible}
  content={<Text>Check this out!</Text>}
  placement="top"
  onClose={() => this.setState({ toolTipVisible: false })}
>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchable}>
    <Text>Press me</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</Tooltip>
```